# pycharm double shift not only open "Search Everywhere" but also change Chinese input method to full-width

Tags: pycharm

How to disable double-shift changing my Chinese input method to full-width but not disable Search Everywhere?

This only happens in PyCharm. Notepad++ and other editors are normal.

what happened if I double shift

[image]

Comment: Btw, I didn't find anything helpful in KeyMap and Registry

Comment: I just add a shortcut SHIFT+MIDDLE_MOUSE_CLICK for Search Everywhere. 
Now SHIFT+MIDDLE_MOUSE_CLICK also switches to full-witdth! I guess it's a bug in Win7 or PyCharm. This is frustrating.